# Issue with ifconfig in a shell script (using cron)

Tags: networking, debian, scripting, cron, ifconfig

If I execute this script manually in Debian:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down
/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "WLAN_NETWORK"
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key myPassword
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

It works fine. It restarts my wifi adapter and reconnects again without problem.
However, it does nothing when I program it with cron (Of course with administrator permissions).

Any hint of what is going on?

Comment: \ is not the path separator on linux. / is. That cannot be the set of commands you are running by hand when you test it.

Comment: Copy and paste your scripts.  Typing them in by hand will lead to errors that distract people from answering the actual question (and may mask other errors in your script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have some "useless use of `sudo`" in this script.  That is, if you can run this successfully:

```
/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Then you're probably already root, so you should be able to:

```
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 essid "WLA_NETWORK"
```

without using `sudo`.

There are a couple of things that could prevent your script in its current form from running:

- `sudo` can be configured to require a valid tty (using the `requiretty` configuration directive).  If this flag is active you won't able to use `sudo` via `cron`.
- You're using fully qualified paths for `ifconfig` but not for `iwconfig`.  If this command isn't in the `PATH` available when run via `sudo`, it's not going to work.

Here are somethings you can do to fix it:

- Remove the use of `sudo`.  Either run the entire script via `sudo` or just run it as `root`.
- Replace `iwconfig` and `dhclient` with fully qualified paths.
- Log `stdout` and `stderr` from the script to a file so that you can inspect the output.  Your crontab entry would look something like `* * * * * /path/to/your/script > /tmp/script.log 2>&1`.

If your script is still having problems at this point, any errors logged in the output file show help point the way to a solution.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was not to have written the full paths.